# onActivityResult is not working and the apk crashes

Tags: android, apk, onactivityresult

im trying to write a simple note apk and stuck in the `startActivityForResult` and in `onActivityResult`.

Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

//Global variables to use later
private ArrayList<Note> note;
private ArrayAdapter<Note> adapter;
private Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    note = new ArrayList<Note>() ;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Note>(this, R.layout.edit , note);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Edit.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 12);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            note.add(new Note(data.getStringExtra("subject"), data.getStringExtra("details"))); 

}
```

the second is the Edit page:

```
public class Edit extends Activity{

private Intent recieve;
EditText subject;
EditText details;
String subject_text;
String subject_details;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit);

    recieve = getIntent();

    subject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_subject);
    details = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_details);

    Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_btn);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            subject_text = subject.getText().toString();
            subject_details = subject.getText().toString();

            recieve.putExtra("subject", subject_text);
            recieve.putExtra("details", subject_details);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, recieve);
            finish();

        }
    });
}

}
```

the Note itself is a java class with 2 variables (private String subject;
    private String details;), constructors, getters and setters.

y does the apk crashes and not adding a new Note?

Comment: what is the exception in logcat?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write output of logcat.

Also Try to write this line:

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

After:

```
note.add(new Note(data.getStringExtra("subject"), data.getStringExtra("details")));
```